# Accessing Database Stored Procedure From C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to access the data from my `UserInfo` table, which exists in my database. I created a stored procedure that does a select on that table and trying to execute that stored proc from my c# application.

Currently, if I run a get on `user` i.e. `localhost:12345/user` I get a 500 error. It is getting to my repository layer, but for some reason fails when it hits the `using` statement. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

> Error: 500 Internal Server Error

**Controller**

```
  public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IUserBusiness _userBusiness;

        public UserController(IUserBusiness userBusines)
        {
            _userBusiness = userBusines;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("user")]
        public async Task<ApiResponse<Status, IEnumerable<UserInfo>>> ListUsers()
        {
            return await _userBusiness.ListUsers();
        }
    }
```

**Business Layer**

```
public class UserBusiness : IUserBusiness
{
    public readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserBusiness(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public async Task<ApiResponse<Status, IEnumerable<UserInfo>>> ListUsers()
    {
        return new ApiResponse<Status, IEnumerable<UserInfo>>(Status.Success, await _userRepository.ListUsersInfo());
    }
}
```

**Repository Layer**

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly ISqlQueryProvider _sqlQueryProvider;

    public UserRepository(ISqlQueryProvider sqlQueryProvider)
    {
        _sqlQueryProvider = sqlQueryProvider;
    }

    public async Task<List<UserInfo>> ListUserInfo()
    {
        using (var reader = _sqlQueryProvider.Execute(RepositorySettings.DatabaseConnection, ListUserInfo_Proc, null))
        {
            return reader.Read<ListUserInfo>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class UserInfo

{
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public string Username {get; set;}
    // Properties continue...
}
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
Use DatabaseName;
Go

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE ListUserInfo_Proc
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT UserId, UserName -- the list continues
    FROM User
END
```

Comment: Its a 500 Internal Server Error... When I debug through the application, it instantly exits my repository layer after hitting the using statement.

Comment: Of course, it's 500. What is the C# exception that is thrown?

Comment: Is the _sqlQueryProvider  injected and not null?

Comment: What's an ISqlQueryProvider?

Comment: @Igor, it states `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`, which is of type `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: that's the important error. Is it the _sqlQueryProvider? Then you need to create it, or set it, in order to work with it.

Comment: @CodeChaser - all you need to do now is to find what is `null` that should not be.

Comment: @Igor, because I don't have any parameters in my stored proc, I set that section to `null` in my `using` statement. Does that look like I am setting that correctly?

Comment: for example: `using (var reader = _sqlQueryProvider.Execute(RepositorySettings.DatabaseConnection, ListUserInfo_Proc, null))`

Comment: @CodeChaser - I don't know what `ISqlQueryProvider` is, and whether its `Execute` implementation is capable of accepting `null` as third parameter.

Comment: @CodeChaser Based on your comments, you are getting **NullReferenceException**. You want to debug and step through line-by-line, and find which line throws the exception.